# How to read .png file and show as text in a TextBox?

Tags: c#

I need to open a .png file as a string and put it in the textbox.I trying to do that by this code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        text1.Text = dialog.FileName;
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
        text2.Text = text;
    }
```

I need to get in my multiline textbox something like this:

> ‰PNG 
>       IHDR  O   Ů   /ç%O   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±Źüa    pHYs  Ă  ĂÇo¨d 
>   (IDATx^íť˝ŽŢF˛†'T°łUčĐá   *ô,°'Zl˛€®b7t8—0ˇB‡ľ'(;7Tb@p$`ř«Ş9ŐĹźŻŮě˙®ŻŰ{H6«ş^5ÉŤžţ0ăÉÁŰĆ#,WXš*CĆxŰ0˛aEVv¶yŰ¨•ť&ˇÉŘ
>   oFU¬5Ńć$cĽm”ÂrĄIX:čëŢ6ęałĄ)26ŔŰFKŘĽbiÚŚ
>   đ¶a´yŰ…éJśť}ěí“/F×XŮŇ®čëŢŕŇÎFŘ”Ň}šäL/¶ľ=ń÷Ď`Ć¦,ÎŇ$çuq¶Młan¦Ý4)3«MĂ0®ŇŠ”™ÍŘ†‘ś:¦jŮŰM]Śa$${eŁŻx»y;5~yĆ›˛@§i±5ÂŰŇőĹĎ‰MY
>   ·Ň„ľ^ŕmĂ¨U` ŇDĆxŰ0Ś®8´.;ŰĽml°Âčž3š?€6gĆ’p‚+’EîłŃ 6[«ŕ

but I get only one word:

> �PNG

Please, help me!

Comment: You can't use File.ReadAllText as a PNG file doesn't contain text. Have a look at BinaryReader! With a little luck you can display its results, but of course it will just be bytes of mainly incomprehensible data..

Comment: (It looks like the OP wants to list the contents of the file, not extract any relevant text.)

Comment: This smells of trying to solve a solution rather than a problem. There's almost certainly an approach to better meet your end goal than what you're trying to do here. Is viewing some garbled text-representation of a PNG file really what you're after?

Comment: @itsme86, symptom.. but yes, i agree as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary data are best read with the `BinaryReader`. To display them in a `TextBox` you need to replace the 0x00 character so it won't disrupt the Text in the control.

This will replace the 0x00 character by a '.' :

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(yourFile, FileMode.Open)))
{
    var data =  br.ReadChars  ((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in data) 
             if ((int)c > 0) sb.Append(c.ToString()); else sb.Append(".");
    text2.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

**Edit:**

Your original code will also work if you modify the final assignment like this:

```
text2.Text = text.Replace((char)0, '.');
```

Explanation: In C# a string can hold arbitrary bit patterns; but the old `Winform TextBox` is still the same as way back before C#, probably written in  C++ and will not handle the old string termination character 0x0 correctly.

While the original problem is not so much the use of `File.ReadAllText`, it is well worth having the `BinaryReader` with its many interesting methods in your toolbox..

And the result is not totally useless - I just found that my test file has an embedded Photoshop ICC profile  ;-)

Comment: Thank you for help. It works perfect. I was need this to get information from game replay file, but it's hard to explain what i want on anyone unknown file.

Comment: Good. Please also see my edit..! (If it works for you, you may want to _accept_ the answer..)

Comment: Ohh, sorry it was my first question on this site. Of course answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you are trying to do this, but If that's what you really want you can use base64 encoded string

```
Read a Image file:
Bitmap loadedBitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(dialog.Filename);
Image imgFile = Image.FromFile(dialog.Filename);


using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    text2.Text = base64String;
  }
```

and when you are reading that string back, you can do the reverse and convert base64 encoded string into an image....